# JQuery Mobile Panel refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, panel

I am using the JQuery Mobile Panel to dynamically load content on multiple buttons using the following code

```
$('#myPanel').empty();
$('#myPanel').append('<h2>Panel Header</h2><div><img src="images/inputsection-A.jpg"></div><a    href="#pageone" data-rel="close" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-shadow ui-corner-all ui-btn-a ui-icon-delete ui-btn-icon-left" data-inline="true">Close panel</a>').panel().enhanceWithin();
$("[data-role=panel]").panel().enhanceWithin();
//$( "#myPanel").panel( "refresh" );

    $("#myPanel").panel( "open" );
        $( "#myPanel" ).trigger( "updatelayout" );
```

All works as expected but the CSS styling is not applied and the close button no longer work. I have read some other issues regarding the refreshing of content and not being able to attach themes to panel elements. I have trawled through Jquery Mobile documentation but am lost due to the forever changing code demos. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `$("#myPanel .ui-panel-inner").empty()` and `$("#myPanel .ui-panel-inner").append()`. I dont know what type of elements you're dynamically adding, but anyway, `.panel()` isn't needed here.